# Can't connect to my google cloud server via RDP

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, google-compute-engine, cloud, connection

I have a google cloud server, I've been using it for months and I always connect to it by downloading the RDP file and it always worked.

But today I'm getting [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll1o2.png) when I try to connect.

> Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these
>   reasons:
>
> 1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
>   2) The remote computer is turned off
>   3) The remote computer is not available on the network
>
> Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the
>   network, and that remote access is enabled.

I didn't change any setting, I tried everything, reset the server, create a new instance, deactivate my firewall, nothing has worked so far...

Comment: what do you mean by "reset the server"?

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. We require all posts to be in English, so I have added the English translation of the error message.

Comment: There is a reset option on the instance

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to reset your windows password first by doing it in the console by clicking on the arrow next to the "RDP" button and select "Set Windows password" a new password will be generated for you (assuming that your firewall rule is set correctly to allow the port 3389).

If the RDP is not enabled I suggest you to run the "mstsc /admin" in your client computer (as [Microsoft](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/c15f0c14-d95b-42cd-aff5-7e36df7a5141/cant-no-longer-connect-to-a-2012-server-hosted-on-the-cloud-because-of-a-terminal-server-error?forum=winserverTS) described). This should allow you to open an Admin RDP session and a Powershell command line popup (in case for a recovery) and see this [document](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-remotely-enable-and-disable-rdp-remote-desktop/).

Answer (score 0):

The official GCP Documentation for [Troubleshooting RDP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp) is quite complete, I would suggest to finish these steps first and add any details in your post from your troubleshooting.

You must also consider what operation are being done on your server, a simple background overview of what your server is doing as it may also be a factor of the issue you are encountering.

For a more detailed and specific information for RDP on windows OS, you can also check this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/troubleshoot/rdp-error-general-troubleshooting) from the Microsoft website.